# animate CGAffineTransformScale within margins

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to animate the size of a UIView with a random factor repeatedly as follows, but I need to make sure it doesn't shrink/grow beyond limits.
This is my attempt:

```
-(void)animateView{
    float percentage =50;
    float rnd = (100 +((float)rand())/RAND_MAX * percentage - percentage/2)/100;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         myView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(myView.transform, rnd, rnd);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self animateView];

                     }
     ];

}
```

So, somewhere in this loop, I need to get the **original size** of myView, and get a relative growth to that size, rather than to the current size of myView.

I am aware of *CGAffineTransformIdentity*, but can't figure out how to put that into this loop.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try to create the instance of CGAffineTransform initialTransform; and preserve  initialTransform = myView.transform; initial value in did load later use it below way : -

```
myView.transform = initialTransform;
```

in top of your animateView method.